# Timeout in createReadStream pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have an issue with Promise and an API rate limit.

I want to read a CSV file and call an API for each line of this CSV.

Here is what I did:

```
fs.createReadStream("./input.csv")
      .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 1 }))
      .on("data", async (row) => {
        promises.push(processData(row, data));
        await timeout();
      })
      .on("end", async () => {
        await Promise.all(promises);
        stringify(data, (err, output) => {
          fs.writeFileSync("output.csv", output);
        });
        resolve();
      })
      .on("error", function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  });
```

with processData being:

```
async function processData(row, data) {
  const firstName = row[0];
  const infos = await callAPI(firstName);
  await timeout();
  const newRow = [
    firstName,
    infos
  ];
  data.push(newRow);
  return data;
}
```

and the timeout function:

```
function timeout() {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(resolve, randomIntFromInterval(3000, 39990))
  );
}
```

It doesn't work, all the promise start at the same time and the API is flooded. I tried to put the timeout() before the promises.push() but it doesn't work either…

What did I miss?

Comment: _"What did I miss?"_ `.on("data", async (row) => {` doesn't wait for the previous line. `await timeout();` doesn't make anything useful. `.on("end", async () => {` also doesn't wait for all callbacks in `.on("data", async (row) => {`.

Comment: Use `for await` to iterate the stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer thanks to @jabaa comment

Here is the fix:

```
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./input.csv');
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.csv');

  const parser = parse({ delimiter: ',', from_line: 1 });
  readStream.pipe(parser);

  for await (const row of parser) {
    promises.push(processData(row, data));
    await timeout();
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);

  stringify(data, (err, output) => {
    writeStream.write(output);
    console.log('OK');
  });

  console.log('end');
```